# Pandas read_csv strange behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

Please try to understand the reason of the following read_csv behaviour:
I am trying to read a huge file in chunks

```
c=1
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
   print 'chunk ', str(c), ' started'
   ....data normalization....
   ....saving the transformed data to file....
```

I get an error like this:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (...) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
chunk  19  started
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

from the error I can see, that for some reason at chunk 19 pandas interpreted the float data as string, and cannot perform '-' operation.

However, if I skip 18 chunks, and start from chunk 19 it goes well. 
Intuition says it might be some memory problem, but I would like understand the reason.

Comment: Have you tried "Specify[ing] dtype option?"

Comment: e.g. ` dtype = {‘col1’: np.float64, ‘col2: np.int32}`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a memory problem.

Pandas makes guesses about what the data types should be if you don't specify the `dtype` argument. Sometimes, it realises that it's made a mistake, and will convert the data type of a column on the fly, if it thinks that's the correct thing to do. In this case, it would appear that it's guessing that the correct type is a numerical one, and then later on encountering some data that makes it think that the column should really be strings, and is converting. Does the data have anything like `'N/A'` in it, by any chance?

Just specify the `dtype` argument. It will make the `read_csv` faster and more efficient, and you'll either fix the problem, or get a better idea of what's causing it.

Comment: No, no chance for n/a. There was a chance for some strings, but at the end it processed ALL chunks correctly (when skipping chunks already processed on the previous run). If I specify the dtype argument, it throws the error like that: wrong type for float64: 0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0. ...